# How to crop rectangles in opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, android

I manage to draw two rectangles from an image I captured. The question is, how to crop them out and save them individually so that I can perform my OCR in each of it? I have tried searching but I can't find what I wanted...

What I have done so far ..

```
  Mat imageMat = new Mat();
  Mat resizeImg = new Mat();
  Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

  //Size(width,height)
  Size imageSize = new Size(1000,800); 

  Utils.bitmapToMat(image, imageMat);
  //Resize Image

  Imgproc.resize(imageMat,resizeImg,imageSize);

  //convert the resized image to bitmap
  image = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizeImg.cols(), resizeImg.rows(), 
  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  //convert back to Mat
  Utils.bitmapToMat(image, imageMat);

  //Create rectangles
  Imgproc.rectangle(imageMat,new Point(0,150), new Point(500,250), new Scalar(255, 0, 255),1);
   Imgproc.rectangle(imageMat,new Point(0,500), new Point(650,650), new Scalar(255, 0, 255),1);

 //What I have tried doing
 Rect rectCrop = new Rect(0,150,500,250);
 Mat image_output= imageMat.submat(rectCrop);

 Bitmap Cropimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageMat.cols(), imageMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.bitmapToMat(Cropimage, image_output);

  //TODO: save only the content in the rectangles to MAT 

//testing purpose 
 Utils.matToBitmap(imageMat,image);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: Make a clone of the submat rectangle and then do operations on it.

Comment: hey @arqam, Thanks for replying.If you don't mind, can you provide some code example?  I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Wait a minute, I manage to crop it :D Thanks btw :))

Comment: @topacoBoy How?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get croped image with rectangular shape.

```
Rect rect = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
Mat cropedMat = new Mat(mat, rect);
```

if you want you can convert croped mat to bitmap

```
Bitmap Cropedimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropedMat.cols(), cropedMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(cropedMat, Cropedimage);
```

Comment: you don't crop anything